# Mixing background-color of an child with the background-image of the parent element with CSS

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color, mix-blend-mode

I want to mix the background color of an element with the background image of the parent element. With the css property "background-blend-mode" set to "multiply" it works only if color and image are set on the same element. But I want to archive different colors getting mixed on the same background image - so I would have to mix the background image with the colors of the childrens. Is there a way to get there?

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

.mixit-green {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 50px;
}

.mixit-blue {
  background-color: #ddddff;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="mixit-green"></div>
  <div class="mixit-blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's `mix-blend-mode`  not `background-blend-mode`<sup>1</sup>

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

.mixit-green {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 50px;
}

.mixit-blue {
  background-color: #ddddff;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="mixit-green"></div>
  <div class="mixit-blue"></div>
</div>
```

`background-blend-mode` is used when having multiple background. So you can write the above like below:

```css
.bg {
  padding:100px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(#ddffdd 50%,#ddddff 0),
  url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
</div>
```

---

> <sup>1</sup>Defines the blending mode of **each background layer**.
>
> Each background layer must blend with the element’s background layer that is below it and the element’s background color. **Background layers must not blend with the content that is behind the element**, instead they must act as if they are rendered into an isolated group. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#background-blend-mode)</sup>

Comment: Ah, thank you for your fast response! Totally missed this property. :)